# Django: field dependencies

Tags: django, forms, validation, dependencies

I've read over [cleaning and validating fields that depend on each other](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other). However I still can't get my clean function to work in the browser. It currently doesn't do anything. What am I missing?

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from incidents.models import *  
import datetime
from django.utils import dateparse
from django.utils import timezone
from functools import partial
DateInput = partial(forms.DateInput, {'class': 'datepicker'})
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError 

class IncidentSearchForm(forms.Form):

    start_date = forms.DateField(
        label="Incident Date Occurs Between", 
        required=False,
        widget=DateInput()
        )

    end_date = forms.DateField(
        label="And",
        required=False,
        widget=DateInput()
        )

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(IncidentSearchForm, self).clean()
        start_date = cleaned_data.get("start_date")
        end_date = cleaned_data.get("end_date")

        if start_date or end_date:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                "Both date fields are required if trying to search by date."
            )

        if end_date < start_date:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                "End date should be greater than start date."
            )

   def search(self):
      start_date = self.cleaned_data.get('start_date')
      end_date = self.cleaned_data.get('end_date')

      query = Incident.objects.all()

      if start_date is not None:
          query = query.filter(start_date=self.cleaned_data.get('start_date'))
      if end_date is not None:
          query = query.filter(end_date=self.cleaned_data.get('end_date')

      return(query)
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def index(request):

    template = "index.html"                 
    form = IncidentSearchForm(request.GET)

    if 'open' in request.GET:               

        if form.is_valid():                 
            incident_list = form.search()   
            context = { "form": form,                       
                        "incident_list": incident_list}     
            return render(request, template, context)
        else:
            context = { "form": form }      
            return render(request, template, context)

    else:                                   
        form = IncidentSearchForm()
        incident_list = Incident.objects.filter(open = 'True').order_by('-incident_date_reported')
        context = { "form": form,
                    "incident_list": incident_list}
        return render(request, template, context)
```

Comment: You'll need to show your view. And your clean method should return all of `cleaned_data`, not just start_date.

Comment: I think my problem is I'm not returning the `cleaned_data`

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(IncidentSearchForm, self).clean()
    start_date = cleaned_data.get("start_date")
    end_date = cleaned_data.get("end_date")

    if not start_date or not end_date:
        raise forms.ValidationError(
            "Both date fields are required if trying to search by date."
        )

    if end_date < start_date:
        raise forms.ValidationError(
            "End date should be greater than start date."
        )

   return cleaned_data
```

Comment: Thanks. I think my problem is I'm not returning the `cleaned_data`.

Comment: When I return `cleaned_data` where is it getting sent to? I'm still not getting it to work. Where do I call clean()?

Comment: clean() is executed called when you cal form.is_valid(), if it is invalid then cleaned_data will be sent back to template.

Comment: so all I did was customize `clean()`? Still not working.... I'm trying things though. hang on.

Comment: I want to use `end_date` and `start_date` in my `def search()` how can I do that if I `return cleaned_data`?

Comment: Still I didn't get, what your needs.

Comment: I'm not sure what to do when I `return cleaned_data`. I want to use `end_date` and `start_date` in my `def search()` method as seen in the original post, but I can't seem to use them if I have the return in `clean()`. Does that make more sense?

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
from dateutil.parser import parse

def search(self):
  start_date = self.cleaned_data.get('start_date')
  end_date = self.cleaned_data.get('end_date')

  query = Incident.objects.all()

  if start_date is not None:
      query = query.filter(start_date=parse(self.cleaned_data.get('start_date')))
  if end_date is not None:
      query = query.filter(end_date=parse(self.cleaned_data.get('end_date'))

  return query
```

Comment: I'm not sure we are on the same page. Why can't I use `end_date` and `start_date` in my my `search()` method? I would rather create a query in there than put this in the view. Unless that isn't possible? and what does `return cleaned_data` return exactly?

Comment: I have edited answer, here parse(self.cleaned_data.get('end_date')) will convert your string date to python date object.

Comment: That's not my issue. I will try to find the answer somewhere else. Thanks!